# How i can play all types of video on html page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How i can play all types of video on html page in html  tag.
i've tried it in bootstrap model with html video attribute, but it support only three format like mp4, ogg and wmp

Comment: it has nothing to do with bootstrap

Comment: you can use jwplayer plugin to play all formats http://www.jwplayer.com/products/jwplayer/html5-and-flash/

Comment: It ha nothing to do with CSS either.

Comment: you might take a look at some video player plugins.

Comment: Any reason why you would not use services like YouTube or Vimeo in this case? One of their greatest benefits are that they create different versions of your video automatically, therefore making it work in multiple devices. As a bonus, it does not eat your web server bandwidth.

Comment: i want o store all video on my own server.

Comment: how can i use multiple (dynamically fetched) images in jwplayer.com player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'All types' is a big goal. What types of extensions do you want to play? Be more specific.

HTML5 video only supports MP4, OGG and WEBM.

In my opinion, the best way to go is MP4, because all modern browsers support MP4 nowadays (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp).

Comment: MP4 is clearly the best and widely supported format these days, but yet it lacks support on some devices. Issues are in this case more device than browser related, though the service between the issue is always the browser.

Comment: That's true, but all formats may cause trouble on some devices. I think it's safe to say that the least trouble is to expect with MP4.

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap does nothing in this case and HTML5 is still under development so many browsers will not support all the features of HTML5.

Please see [Supported media formats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats) for more information